# Change class of div onclick and remove class when onclick of a button

Tags: jquery

I want, that if I click the "btn", that the added classes on "outer" and "btn" gets removed and the previous classes gets added. I already tried with removeClass, but it doenst work? How can I do it? I'm pretty new to jQuery. Also ignore the errors in the code snippet. I don't get them on my website.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#outer" ).click(function() {
       $( "#outer" ).addClass( "block01_big" );
       $( "#btn" ).addClass( "button_visible" );
    });
       
   <!-- edited -->       
   $( "#btn" ).click(function() {
     $( "#outer" ).removeClass( "block01_big" );
     $( "#btn" ).removeClass( "button_visible" );
     <!-- i also tried -->
     $( "#outer" ).addClass( "block01" );
     $( "#btn" ).addClass( "button_invisible" );
   });
});
```

```css
.container {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 99vw;
    background-color: red;
    
    overflow: hidden;
  }

.block01 { <!-- Normal Class for outer -->
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: 33.33333%;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative; 
    
    transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out;
  }

.block01_big { <!-- outer gets bigger, by jQuery -->
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 999;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }

.button_invisible { <!-- Not visible to the user -->
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    border: none;
    
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

.button_visible { <!-- Button gets visible, by jQuery -->
    margin-right: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 75px;
    
    height: 75px;
    width: 200px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block01" id="outer"> <!-- jQuery: onClick, change outer class to .block01_big & bt" to button_visible -->
    <button class="button_invisible" id="btn">Back</button> <!-- jQuery: onClick, change outer class to .block01 & btn to button_invisible (doesnt work)-->
  </div>
</div>


<!-- If I click first on the outer, the classes from outer and btn should change. Now my Problem: How can I do it, if I click the button, that the added classes from outer and btn gets removed? -->
```

Comment: did you include jquery?

Comment: Since `#btn` is inside `#outer`, you need to stop propagation when they click on the button.

Comment: Where is your code for clicking on `#btn`?

Comment: yes i have <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> in my header. i dont have a code for clicking on the btn. i tried but nothing changed. thats why i m asking. also here's a picture to demonstrate my problem better: http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4492/r89rauf9_png.htm

Comment: You need to show what you tried, so we can explain what you did wrong and how to fix it. What do you think this is, a service to get people to write code for you whenever you get stuck?

Comment: Maybe `toggleClass()` is what you want?

Comment: i also thought about that, but i tried the "dumb proof" version + i dont know how to use toggleclass

Comment: How do you click on something that is invisible? And if you click on something, the parent is also clicked.

Comment: the button turns visible as i click on the div.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, somehow toggle didnt work. But now it does. Solved. For guys, who have the same problem: just use `toggleClass` instead of `addClass`

(Thanks to Barmar, as he already mentioned it)